# Increment counter on DataBase using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field on my database that stores a number of clicks, and want to increment that when I click in a link(`<a href="#selecoes" data-identity="31" id="clicks" clicks="0">`) of my tag cloud. Note that I get the number of clicks throught my webservice. This is I do so far:

index.html

```
<div id="tags">
      <ul id="tagList">
       <li>
           <a href="#selecoes" data-identity="31" id="clicks" clicks="0"><img src='.../>Brasil</a>
       </li>                
</ul>
```

main.js

```
    $('#tagList a').live('click', function() {
        findByIdSelecoes($(this).data('identity'));
    });

    function findByIdSelecoes(id) {
        console.log('findByIdSelecoes: ' + id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURLSelecoes + '/id/' + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $('#btnDelete').show();
                console.log('findByIdSelecoes success: ' + data.nome);
                currentWine = data;
                renderDetails(currentWine);
                findJogadoresBySelecao(id);
                addClick(currentWine);

            }
        });
    }


function addClick(selecao) {
    console.log('addClick na seleção: ' + selecao.id_selecao);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: rootURLSelecoes + '/update/' + selecao.id_selecao,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('clicks updated successfully');


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('updateWine error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}



function formToJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "clicks": ($('#clicks').val())++ // i dont know what i have to do so i try this(don't work)
        });
}
```

I can't update the dataBase when I click the link in the list. The function formToJSON doesn't increment the value in the database.

Comment: Have you got any problems? What's the actual question?

Comment: I can't update dataBase when I click in the link in the list.

Comment: @user3658717: Where does it fail?  Is there a JavaScript error in the browser console?  Is the AJAX request sent to the server?  What is the server's response?  Is there an error in the server-side code?  We can't debug this for you, you have to put in at least *some* effort.

Comment: The only thing I wan't is to increment the counter in DataBase, but the funtion formToJSON doesn't update the counter. It seems that the server isn't receiving any code at all, seeing as there's no server response.

Comment: @user3658717 the comment made by David reflects the nature of my question. The bottomline is, there's very little we can't do unless we know what's failing, there are three major components involved 1. Client Browser (JS), Server Code and Database. So please add more details before this question gets closed...

Comment: mate, debug it, set breakpoints, sniff the network traffic. You don't need to be a wizard with special tools, just use your browser dev tools...press F12 and play around with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

Make a var number like global, and do this:

```
function addClick(selecao) {
    console.log('addClick na seleção: ' + selecao.id_selecao);
    number = parseInt(selecao.clicks,10);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: rootURLSelecoes + '/update/' + selecao.id_selecao,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert("Done: " +number);




        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('updateWine error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}


function`enter code here` formToJSON() {
    var ola = parseInt(number,10);
    ola = ola +1;
    return JSON.stringify({
        "clicks": parseInt(ola,10)
        });
}
```